# How to do python inputs for words

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
noteinput2 = str(input("What is my favorite color?"))
if noteinput2 == "blue" :
    print("correct")
```

How could I make this work, I'm a little confused, I can do it with numbers but not words?

## this is being done in python 3

I end up obtaining this error when I input blue, I'm going to add an else statement for incorrect, but I can't get the correct to run in the first place.

Here is the report I get back when I type in blue.

```
What is my favorite color?blue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/2g/xlkssb4j67xd2m9y1kvxwg3r0000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/Testcoding-405652050.072.py", line 73, in <module>
    noteinput2 = str(input("What is my favorite color?"))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'blue' is not defined
logout
```

Comment: How does it not work already?

Comment: there's nothing wrong here...

Comment: Please describe what your current output is and what your expected output is.

Comment: Perhaps your error is that there are leading and/or trailing spaces in the input. Use `input("What is my favorite color? ").strip()` to remove those pesky spaces

Comment: I keep obtaining this error: 
What is my favorite color?blue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/2g/xlkssb4j67xd2m9y1kvxwg3r0000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/Testcoding-405652050.072.py", line 73, in <module>
    noteinput2 = str(input("What is my favorite color?"))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'blue' is not defined
logout

Comment: Please edit your error into your post. Don't write it as a comment

Comment: Input tries to interpret what you type and doesn't recognize the "variable". Put your response in quotes and all is well

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3 and not Python 2?

Comment: I get the same error when I do this - but http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html says it is correct??

Comment: OK, what interpreter are you using? Some don't support input.

Comment: I could not tell you @Lotus, What i know is that i downloaded python 3 from the website, and am running it on macbook text wrangler with the #!/usr/local/bin/python3python  in the first line.

Comment: I posted the answer.. @John

Comment: Right before the `noteinput2 = ` line, add two extra lines: `import sys` and then `print(sys.version)`, and let us know what it reports.

Answer (score 1):

This applies to python 2
Check this http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input, the input function evaluates what user provides. If you want to use this function then you can type your input within double quotes ("") to make sure it's received as a string i.e.:

```
"blue"
```

not

```
blue
```

The other alternative is to use the raw_input function. See code bellow, don't need to put double quotes for this :

```
input = raw_input("enter input")
print(input)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean? Clearly, OP is checking `noteinput == "blue"` with the quotes around `blue`. So what exactly do you mean here?

Comment: Okay it works when i add " " in the input, but lets say for a user who doesn't know to do that, is it possible to recode it so the input blue alone works?

Comment: raw_input no longer exists in Python 3! You are getting this info from Python 2x docs. Op is using Python 3

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 `input` will work for both numbers and strings. I think this is a problem in the IDE or online compiler you are using. The problem is in your Macbook TextWrangler. If you try your code in the following online IDE it works(which i just did): [Ideone](http://ideone.com/IyRG40)